# How do I render with the viewport lighting?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, lighting, shadows

Blender noob here. I'm trying to make some renders, but when I do the render looks really dark. I can add lights, but that's not what I want. I just want the render to look like it does in the viewport, without extra lighting or shadows.

Basically I want the render to look like this (without the wireframe):

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to pull this off?

Comment: Alternatively you could disable the *Show Overlays* and use *View > Viewport Render Image*.